# Finding occurrence of number in informatica

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

I have concatenated value of

> 1.abc..2.def..2.ghi..3.jkl

in one port and in expression i would like to find the occurrence of numbers associated with each string and after that assign it to port. 
For the above Question o/p be like this

> 2.2.def.ghi

which means number 2 comes two times and it is associated with def and ghi.
Kindly Help.

Comment: this value `1.abc..2.def..2.ghi..3.jkl` is coming as 1 row or different rows like `1.abc` , `2.def`. Also you want output for each each number in a different row?

Comment: This value is coming as one row and i want to get o/p for each number in different rows.2.2.def.ghi means number 2 comes two times and it is associated with def and ghi.1.1.abc means 1 comes one times and associated with abc and so on.

Comment: Which db/version are you using?

Comment: It is very difficult to handle this in mapping. You either need to handle it at DB level, or by a java code and call it from java transformation.

Comment: How can i use it at DB level?

Comment: in your example, do you need just `2.2.def.ghi` as output, or other values too?

Comment: Other's data too.like 1.1.abc which means 1 is coming only one times and associated with abc.